# calculate abs from delta between values of in 2 columns in dataframe using lambda function

Tags: python-3.x

I have a data frame table.
Need to calculate abs from the delta between 'price' and 'pbeach' columns and add the result new column as 'pdiff' in this data frame.
Should be done using lambda function.
Here's what I do (dat - my dataframe:

```
f = lambda x,y: np.abs(x - y)
dat['pdiff'] = dat.loc[:, ['price', 'pbeach']].apply(f, axis = 1)
```

What is wrong?

```
f = lambda x,y: np.abs(x - y)
dat['pdiff'] = dat.loc[:, ['price', 'pbeach']].apply(f, axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df['diff'] = df.apply(lambda x: np.abs(x['price'] - x['pbeach']), axis=1)
```